# getIdentifier method of PersistenceUnitUtil not working for Composite keys

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am getting below error when trying to retrieve identity using getIdentifier method of PersistenceUnitUtil. Is there anything I am doing wrong.

> Local Exception Stack:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: An internal error occurred accessing the primary key object [202].
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.sample.Person --> [DatabaseTable(PERSON)])
>
> at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.errorUsingPrimaryKey(DescriptorException.java:1923)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CMP3Policy$FieldAccessor.setValue(CMP3Policy.java:686)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.CMPPolicy.createPrimaryKeyInstance(CMPPolicy.java:453)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getIdentifier(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:75)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getIdentifier(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:679)
>           at com.sample.PersistenceUtil.getEntityIdentifier(PersistenceUtil.java:27)
>           at com.sample.PersistenceUtil.getEntityIdentifier(PersistenceUtil.java:18)
>           at com.sample.OverrideUtilTest.canconfirmEntityEqualsforCompositeId2(OverrideUtilTest.java:147)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CMP3Policy$FieldAccessor.setValue(CMP3Policy.java:682)
>           ... 29 more

The code sample I am trying is this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PersonPK.class)
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_C")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "NAME_C")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_C")
    private String country;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String code, String country) {
        this.code = code;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }
}

public class PersonPK implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final String code;
    private final String country;

    public PersonPK(String city, String country) {
        super();
        this.code = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
      return super.equals (object);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The code to retrieve identity I am using is

```
getEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName).getPersistenceUnitUtil()
                .getIdentifier(entity);
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> The primary key class must be public and must have a public no-arg constructor.

Hibernate message in similar situation is a little bit more informative

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : PersonPK

**Solution:** Add default constructor to `PersonPK`